# How do I multiply a output from division in Java Script HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have HTML code that when you type in a number, it divides 30 from the input. I want it to take the output, multiply it by 10, then display the number. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Input: <input id="input" type="text"><br /> Output: 
<div id="division"></div>
<br>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var division = document.getElementById('division');
var DivisionNum = 30;
var MultiplcationNum = 10;

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
 
  var val = parseFloat(input.value);
  if (!isNaN(val)) {

    division.innerHTML = val / DivisionNum;
  } else {
    division.innerHTML = 'Please enter a number.';
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am wanting it to take the divided number, and multiply it by 10.

Comment: Whatever you are using to learn Javascript, if it tells you how to do division but not multiplication, I'd be looking elsewhere.

Comment: I know how to do multiplication in Javascript but I just need help making it divide, then multiply a single input.

Comment: What's the problem: `val / DivisionNum * MultiplicationNum`

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I didnt know that you could do more than one expressions at once.

Comment: Yep! You can stack pretty much anything there, whole funky equations on one line. I'd recommend putting in brackets in to make it absolutely clear what order things should be happening though e.g. `(Val / DivisionnNum) * MultiplicationNum`. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for one line input calculation.

Then I leave this to you.

> You can use eval() to takes a javaScript expression as a string and executes it.

```html
Input: <input id="input" type="text" oninput="null ? document.getElementById('division').innerHTML = '' : !isNaN(this.value) ? document.getElementById('division').innerHTML = eval(this.value / 30 * 10) : document.getElementById('division').innerHTML = 'Please enter a number.'"><br /> Output: 
<div id="division"></div>
```